# Cleanest way to wait for a condition in Selenium 2/Java?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find the cleanest code for waiting for a particular string to appear in a page. The best I have right now is the rather clunky

```
new Wait() {
    @Override
    public boolean until() {
        return !webDriver.findElement(By.tagName("html"))
               .getText().contains("please choose another");
    }
}.wait("wait failed!", 60000);
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Don't worry too much about the foolish nature of the condition, BTW. I picked an example more or less at random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is really what you want to do, then

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'please choose another')]"));
```

with an [Implicit wait](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#implicitlyWait%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) seems a little bit better to me (from the 'clean code' point of view) since it's just one line of code.

Comment: Ah, OK, and then because it's all one function, the implicit wait will cause it to wait until the condition is true. Thanks!

Comment: implicit wait will NOT wait for a condition. It only waits for a certain amount of time. If you want to wait for a condition use WebDriverWait as Aditi suggested

Comment: @Tarken Yes and no. With the specified XPath, it waits for the condition (or a configurable timeout). It's just a matter of taste / your needs whether you use a complex oneliner with some advanced XPath, or a "clean" `Wait`.

Comment: @Slanec findElement waits for every By. condition doesn't matter if it is xpath cssSelector or something else. The downside of only using implicitlyWait is that it is global. With WebDriverWait you can create waits for methods individually if you are waiting for somethings like ajax calls. Normally you should use a combination of both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Webdriver's built in methods for explicitly waiting - see the [examples here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html).

Note that if it is possible, it is better to check if the text is in a specific element rather than anywhere. Checking that it is anywhere can lead to false positives (ie if someone adds the same string somewhere else on the page, you will no longer be checking what you thought you were).

Comment: The example in that link actually looks more complex to me than what I wrote. (Don't worry about the silly nature of the condition, it's just a random example.)

Answer (score 0):

Create a WebDriverWait class object

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 500);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'please choose another']")));
```